# Tableau: turning a single row into multiple rows

Tags: tableau-api

My current Tableau table looks like this:

[image: Chart Image]

I am wondering if there is there a way to split the row after every three elements to make it more compact?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add more details to your question. In its current state, it is not clear about what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well your problem to change a viz like this one
[image]

To this one
[image]

you can create a rows and columns dimension calculation that determine the position of each of the elements for example:

```
    rows=
    CASE [Col]
        WHEN "A" THEN 1
        WHEN "B" THEN 1
        WHEN "C" THEN 1
        WHEN "D" THEN 2
        WHEN "E" THEN 2
        WHEN "F" THEN 2
        WHEN "G" THEN 3
    END

    columns=
    CASE [Col]
        WHEN "A" THEN 1
        WHEN "B" THEN 2
        WHEN "C" THEN 3
        WHEN "D" THEN 1
        WHEN "E" THEN 2
        WHEN "F" THEN 3
        WHEN "G" THEN 1
    END
```

Or use a formula with INDEX() and module operator (%) like position = INDEX() % 3